# Regex in Notepad++: Find all 'INSERT INTO...;' queries

Tags: regex, search, notepad++

I have a big sql file that contains a lot of 'create table ...' and 'insert ...' queries.
Now I want to eliminate all the 'insert' queries from the file.
The insert queries are somewhat like:

```
INSERT INTO 'some_table' (col1, col2, col3) values
('val11','val12','val13'),
('val21','val22','val23'),
('val31','val32','val33');
```

Using **Notepad++**
I want to find and delete all these 'INSERT' queries using regular expression.

When I tried finding with the regex **`INSERT INTO((.*\r\n)*)`** then it selects from the start of the first INSERT query till the end of the file.
Now when I place the semicolon after this reqex (**`INSERT INTO((.*\r\n)*);`**), it finds nothing?
How can I terminate the regex search with semicolons (`;`)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The semicolon falls before the end of the line, and that is where it needs to be in your regex.

```
INSERT INTO(([^;]*\r\n)*(.*;(\r\n|$)))
```

A more reliable approach is:

```
INSERT INTO[\s\S]*?(?<=;)\s*$
```

which allows you to have semicolon literals in your query.

Answer (score 2):

```
INSERT INTO.*?;
```

choose the `match newline option`

---

You were matching it greedily(`.*`)...use lazy quatifier(`.*?`)

No need of `\r\n`...

Comment: gr8, how easy it is when the `match newline` option chosen !! Thanx.

Comment: +1, but semicolons in literals (eg. `'val11;'`) would break this.

Comment: @Asad hmm..that would break it