# Find all (multiline) 'SELECT...' queries that doesn't contain a certain word

Tags: regex, notepad++

In my java file there are many sql queries assigned to java strings like:

```java
/* ... */
String str1 = "SELECT item1, item2 from table1 where this=that and MYWORD=that2 and this3=that3";
/* ... */
String str2 = "SELECT item1, item2 from table1 where this=that and" + 
                " MYWORD=that2 and this3=that3 and this4=that4";
/* ... */
/* ... */
String str3 = "SELECT item1, item2 from table2 where this=that and this2=that2 and" +
                " this3=that3 and this4=that4";
/* ... */
String str4 = "SELECT item1, item2 from table3 where this=that and MYWORD=that2" +
                " and this3=that3 and this4=that4";
/* ... */
String str5 = "SELECT item1, item2 from table4 where this=that and this2=that2 and this3=that3";
/* ... */
```

Now I want to **find out the 'SELECT...' queries that doesn't contain the word 'MYWORD' in it**.

From one of my previous S/O question I got the [answer how to find all the '`SELECT...`' queries](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13620958/regex-in-notepad-find-all-insert-into-queries), but I need to extend that solution to find the ones that doesn't contain certain word.

I have tried the regex **`SELECT(?!.*MYWORD).*;`** that can't find the  multiline queries (like **str3** above), finds only the single line ones.

I've also tried the regex **`SELECT[\s\S]*?(?!MYWORD).*(?<=;)$`** that finds all the queries and is unable to determine whether the word 'MYWORD' is present in the query or not.

I know I'm very near to the solution, still can't figure it out.
Can anyone help me, please?
(I am using notepad++ on windows)

Comment: Can there ever be escaped quotes in your strings? Like `"A 2\" by 4\" board"`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem with the first regex is that `.` doesn't match a newline.  In normal regexes, there is an option to change that, but I don't know whether that feature exists in notepad++.

The problem with the second regex is that is matches "select, then some stuff, then anything that doesn't match MYWORD, then more stuff, then a semicolon" Even if MYWORD exists, the regex engine will happily match `(?!MYWORD)` to some other part of the string that is not MYWORD.

Something like this should work (caveat: not tested on Notepad++):

```
SELECT(?![^;]*MYWORD)[^;]*;
```

Instead of `.`, match anything that is not a semicolon.  This should allow you to match a newline.

Beyond that, it is also important that you don't allow a semicolon to be part of the match.  Otherwise, the pattern can expand to gobble up multiple `SELECT` statements as it tries to match.

Comment: +1, I first thought "What if there is a semicolon inside your `SELECT` statement?", but they don't appear to be legal there, so this approach is probably just fine.

Comment: @TimPietzcker, technically a robust solution would require full parsing of Java and SQL!  For example, you could have an escaped semicolon in a string in the select statement, or the word "SELECT" in a Java comment.  But I think we can set the bar a little lower for a text editor regex.

Comment: Thanks a lot. It's working exactly as I expected !! I just needed to add an extra space after `SELECT` to avoid matching the java statements like: `boolean isSelected = 1;`

Answer (score 1):

Try this (on a current version of Notepad++ using Perl-compatible regexes; older versions don't support multiline regexes):

```
SELECT (?:(?!MYWORD)[^"]|"\s*\+\s*")*"\s*;
```

**Explanation:**

```
SELECT       # Match SELECT
(?:          # Match either...
 (?!MYWORD)  #  (as long as it's not the word MYWORD)
 [^"]        #  any character except a quote
|            # or
 "\s*        #  an ending quote, optional whitespace,
 \+\s*       #  a plus sign, optional whitespace (including newlines),
 "           #  and another opening quote.
)*           # Repeat as needed.
"\s*;        # Match a closing quote, optional whitespace, and a semicolon.
```